# Fluent NHibernate - How to insert a child object without get it by NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm inserting a parent object in the database using Fluent NHibernate, 
This object have a child, and this child is already persisted in database, but I only have the id from this child.

How can I insert the parent object with his foreign key (child) only setting the id to a child object?

Example:

```
ObjectParent parent = new ObjectParent();
ObjectChild child = new ObjectChild();

child.Id = 5; // 5 is the id from the child in the database
parent.Child = child;

Service.Create(parent); // here I need to insert the parent with the referenced foreign key (id = 5)
```

EDIT:

I can't get the child object from the database.

Answer (score 1):

On the NHibernate level you can use a proxy created by the `ISession`.

If you can be sure, that the ID (e.g. 5) exists, you can call `session.Load<Child>(5)`. This will return a `proxy` for you, which in fact do not have to be loaded at all. Inserting that proxy into parent, will issue the INSERT statement only for the *Parent*

```
Create(Parent parent, int childId)// = 5)
{

  child = session.Load<Child>(5);

  parent.Child = child;

  session.Save(parent);
```

Extended:

Another way how to handle references, could be different mapping. I usually use these two properties for Reference and its RefererenceId:

```
<property not-null="true" name="ChildId" insert="false" update="false" />
<many-to-one name="Child" column="ChildId" />
```

In your case, solution would be use similar solution, but with updatable ID proeprty

```
<property not-null="true" name="ChildId" />
<many-to-one name="Child" column="ChildId" insert="false" update="false" />
```

And the Parent having both properties

```
class Parent 
{
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public virtual int ChildId { get; set; }
```

And the code like

```
parent.ChildId = 5;
```

Comment: I can't get the child from the database.

Comment: I've provided you with another approach. This will work for you, you will need to change your mapping and introduce ChildId property on the Parent

Answer (score 0):

Use [stateless session](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#batch-statelesssession) as it does not care about relations between (sub) entities by default. It brings real performance improvement, see example within [my post](http://martin.podval.eu/2010/12/nhibernate-performance-isssues-insert.html).